# Why don't <2k users get the in-place edit thingy for their own posts?

Tags: feature-request, edits, suggested-edits, privileges

I'm 3k on SO, so I have full edit privileges. One of the nice perks that comes with this is that another page doesn't have to load just so I can make an edit. (Before 2k, a separate page loads to suggest an edit. After 2k, a Gen-U-Wine SuperAwesome InPlaceEdit thingy pops up to replace the post - making it editable in-place, no page-reloading require.)

I know why the non-privileged users don't get the in-place editor: rate limiting. It's harder to choke up a review queue when you have to load a new page to suggest an edit.

However, what about their *own* posts?

<2k users have full edit privileges on their own posts - why not let them have the in-place editor that the >2k users get?

**Suggestion: Let users without edit privs use the in-place editor for their own posts.**

Comment: < 2k users see a vastly different edit page than we do, in particular one with more text. I'm not sure you can cram those into the in-place editor, which is *just* the editor control.

Comment: Has probably to do with the size of the delivered JS. The in-place edit takes some extra space in the JS (which is heavily cached).

Comment: @BoltClock For their own posts, though? Do we need to?

Comment: @Undo: Oh, I missed that somehow. I'm not sure to be honest - it would make things inconsistent for those users (e.g. why is it in-place for own posts and not others).

Comment: @BoltClock I don't know - we could say 'this is a taste of the awesomeness you could achieve. Now go answer something!'

Comment: Note that the <2k users's editor also contain a bunch of guideline on the side meant to educate them (which no one even bother looking at...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

Users without 2k has not yet gained the trust of the community<sup>1</sup> to do edits. They might be new to MarkDown syntax for formatting, and they might not know what constitutes a good edit. The edit screen, which contains information on *How To Edit* and *How To Format*, gives them short and sweet guideline on the matter.

<sup><sup>1</sup> In reality, reputation is not a good indication of editing skill, since 2000 reputation can be gained very quickly. However, it is a subject of discussion for another time.</sup>

The in-place edit is meant for users who have gained the trust of community to do edits on their own, and are expected to have known the syntax and what makes a proper edit; therefore, they don't need to be shown the guideline that they have already known.

Comment: Yes, I have only been active for a few months - but I like to think I know what I'm doing.